# 45th and 55th percentile

Tags: spss, quantiles

I have a series of data from a household budget survey and want to do the following in SPSS:

Identify the food expenditure shares of total household expenditure that are at the 45th and 55th percentiles across the whole sample. If the survey includes a household weighting variable, the percentile calculation should consider the weight.

I have tried many different ways to define a percentile, but I am not sure what is the correct one in my case. How can I do this? And how can I include the household weight in the calculations? 
Thank you.

Comment: In SPSS, percentules are in Frequencies procedure. And yes, they obey frequency weighting variable which weights the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

The EXAMINE procedure provides five(!) different ways to compute percentages.  Read the descriptions in the CSR under EXAMINE/PERCENTILES to help you decide which is most appropriate for your needs.